# I can't install openCV2.3.1 in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

I downloaded openCV2.3.1. It's the lastest version of openCV. After download I double click OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack and click Run button. It extract file to C:/opencv folder.

1. I build openCV from CMake.
2. I goto VC++2010 Ultimate to build debug and release openCV into folder vc2010 in the opencv folder.
3. I create empty project and **Add New Project Property Sheet**. I Include Directories from C:\opencv\include, **Library Directories** C:\opencv\vc2010\lib .
4. I click **Edit the Additional Dependencies** and add

   opencv_core231d.lib
   opencv_highgui231d.lib
   opencv_imgproc231d.lib
   opencv_features231d.lib
   opencv_calib3d231d.lib

After that, I create .cpp file and include **#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"** but VC++2010 display **error cannot open source file "opencv2/core/core.hpp"**. How to install openCV2.3.1 in VC++2010 please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks for `C:\opencv\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp`, which does not exist.

Add `c:\opencv\modules\core\include` to your path too.

There are a few more modules you need, put them all in.

Answer (score 1):

Config your Opencv 231 with VS 2010 using cMake. 
I recommend you follow good tutorial as shown below 
    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZvjTTK9zTw